# Change width of UITableViewController on iPhone

Tags: uitableview, width

Does anyone know how to change the width of a uitableviewcontroller?  I was thinking maybe I could do it in interface builder because I can't figure it out in the code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View controllers do not have any size attributes associated with them (that information is stored within the view). However, you can change the width of your UITableView by setting 'frame' property or by updating the properties in interface builder (Tools > Inspector > Size). If you have a UITableView contained within a UIView, you should be able to drag to resize in interface builder.

Comment: size is grayed out and not editable.  How do i change the size?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it makes sense to change the width of a View Controller.  I think you want to change the width of a view, like UITableView.