# Is it possible set width of UITableView or cells on iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview, width

Since it's not possible to "hook onto" [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410494/change-width-of-uitableviewcontroller-on-iphone) and get an answer, and none of the answers do it, I thought I'd ask if anyone ever succeeded in doing it and if so, how.

I've created a New File, selected subclass UITableViewController with XIB, and everything works fine. I can set the height of everything (with delegate methods), but not the frame of anything.

Right now the table is as wide as the iPad and it looks kinda corny with the short titles in each cell - and there is nothing in IB that changes the stretching or layout.

I'd be happy with any solution that causes the cells to shrink horizontally - like margins. I tried scrollview insets in IB, but they only add to the size of the scrollview so it gets bigger than the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to subclass UViewController and add a UITableView to it, and make it the size you want in IB.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what it will come to. But I am curious as to whether selecting UITableViewController in the New File guide really blocks all customizability apart from delegate overrides. So I know whether to ever use it in future :)

Comment: I would think since your not making the tableview take up the entire screen you are going to want to include other objects on the screen and you will have to use UIViewController instead of UITableViewController